# angular nativeElement.value does not appear in html

Tags: angular

I work with angular and have an autocomplete input in html

```
   <mat-form-field style="width: 100%;" class="example-full-width">
        <mat-label>Application *</mat-label>
        <input type="text"
               placeholder="Pick one"
               aria-label="Application *"
               matInput
               formControlName="application"
               [matAutocomplete]="autoApp"
               ngbTooltip="{{atleastnumbercharacters}}"
               #applicationRef>
        <mat-autocomplete #autoApp="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="getApplication.bind(this)">
            <mat-option (onSelectionChange)="initializeEnvironments(app)" *ngFor="let app of applications" [value]="app.id">
                {{app.name}}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>
```

In my component I reference the input by

```
@ViewChild("applicationRef") applicationRef: ElementRef;
```

But when I set the value in the input

```
this.applicationRef.nativeElement.value = applicationDto.name;
```

it does not appear in html. Could you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I forgot to tell you that I set

```
this.applicationRef.nativeElement.value = applicationDto.name;
```

in ngAfterViewInit

The solution is the following:

```
setTimeOut( () => {this.applicationRef.nativeElement.value = applicationDto.name;});
```